# Usb mouse driver using LIBUSB

Tags: c++, ubuntu, mouse, driver, libusb

I want to try "userspace" driver(it isn't my code) on Ubuntu. And I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <usb.h>
#include <usbpp.h>

#define DEBUG_LEVEL 0

struct usb_bus *busses,*bus,*dbus;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        struct usb_device *dev;
        char *buf;
        int n,x,r, ret;
        char *ibus, *idev;
        char string[64];
        int found = 0;       
        usb_dev_handle *udev;

        usb_set_debug(DEBUG_LEVEL);

        usb_init(); //initilize the usb library
        usb_find_busses();
        usb_find_devices();
        busses=usb_get_busses();

        //use the command line arguments for Bus and Device
        if (argc >= 3) {
                ibus = argv[1];
                idev = argv[2];
        }
        else { printf("Usage: usbtest <Bus> <Device> [<numBytes>])\n"); exit(1); }

        printf("Bus = %s Device = %s\n", ibus, idev);

        for (bus=busses; bus && (found == 0); bus=bus->next) { // busses loop
                if (strcmp(bus->dirname, ibus) == 0) {
                        for (dev=bus->devices; dev; dev=dev->next) { // devices loop
                                if (strcmp(dev->filename, idev) == 0) { dbus=bus; found=1; break; }
                        }
                }
        }

        if (found == 0) { printf("Unable to find the required device !\nexiting\n"); exit(1); }

        printf("Found device\n");
        printf("Now we are dealing with device from vendor ID : %d (%x) \n",dev->descriptor.idVendor,dev->descriptor.idVendor);
        printf("Trying to open the device...\n");

        if (udev=usb_open(dev)) printf("Device opened successfully.\n");
        else { printf("Operation failed :-("); exit(1);}

        buf=(char*)calloc(1,100);
        if (usb_get_driver_np(udev,0,buf,100)) printf("Could not read the driver name :-( %s\n",buf); 
        else printf("Kernel Using Driver :\n");

        // detach the driver from the kernel , seems to be just like rmmod? 
        if (usb_detach_kernel_driver_np(udev,0)) printf("Error detaching the device :-(\n"); 
        else printf("Device detached successfully from the kernel.\n");

        // reserving the device interface for our application, if another driver/software
        //is using the device , it will return 'interface busy'
        if (r=usb_claim_interface(udev,0)) printf("Interface Claimed !!\n"); 
        printf("Interface Claim Status : %d\n",r);

        printf("Device Protocol : %d\n",dev->descriptor.bDeviceProtocol);
        printf("Report Length : %d\n",dev->descriptor.bLength);
        printf("Decriptor Type : %d\n",dev->descriptor.bDescriptorType);
        printf("End Points : %d\n",dev->config->interface->altsetting->bNumEndpoints);
        printf("Interface Class : %d\n",dev->config->interface->altsetting->bInterfaceClass);
        printf("Protocol : %d\n",dev->config->interface->altsetting->bInterfaceProtocol);
        printf("Interface Number: %d\n",dev->config->interface->altsetting->bInterfaceNumber);
        printf("Device Filename : %s\n",dev->filename);
        printf("Bus Dir Name : %s\n",dbus->dirname);

        usb_get_string_simple(udev,dev->descriptor.iManufacturer,string,sizeof(string));
        printf("Device Manfucaturer : %s\n",string);
        usb_get_string_simple(udev,dev->descriptor.iProduct,string,sizeof(string));
        printf("Product Name : %s\n",string);
        usb_get_string_simple(udev,dev->descriptor.iSerialNumber,string,sizeof(string));
        printf("Device Serial Number: %s\n",string);
        printf("End point addresses : 0x%x\n",dev->config->interface->altsetting->endpoint->bEndpointAddress);

        int numBytes = 4;
        int errCount = 0;
        unsigned char endPoint = 0x81;
    int i;
    int tmp1 = 5;
    int tmp2 = 5;

        // reset usb device if command line numBytes = 0 and exit
        if (argc == 4 && atoi(argv[3]) == 0) { usb_reset(udev); exit(0); }

        // use command line value for numBytes if supplied
        if (argc == 4) numBytes = atoi(argv[3]);
        if (numBytes > 64) numBytes = 64;

        while (1) {  
                for (x=0; x<numBytes; x++)  string[x]=0;

                // read numBytes bytes using interrupt_read,
                r = usb_interrupt_read(udev, endPoint, string, numBytes, 0); 

                system("clear");

        tmp1+=string[1];
        tmp2+=string[2];
        if (tmp1>=0 && tmp2>=0 && tmp1<=150 && tmp2<=50){
        for (i=0;i<tmp2;i++) printf("\n");
        for (i=0;i<tmp1;i++) printf(".");
        if (string[0]==0) printf ("X");
        else if (string[0]==1) printf("L");
        else if(string[0]==2) printf("R");
        else if(string[0]==3) printf("LR");
        else if(string[0]==4) printf("M");
        }
        else {
          if(tmp1<0) tmp1=0;
          else if (tmp1>150) tmp1=150;
          if (tmp2<0) tmp2=0;
          else if (tmp2>50) tmp2=50;
        }
        if (string[3]==1) printf ("\nSCROLL UP");
        if (string[3]==-1) printf ("\nSCROLL DOWN");
        printf ("\n(%d, %d)",tmp1,tmp2);
        if ( r < 0 ) errCount++;
                if (errCount >= 100) break; 

                usb_clear_halt(udev,endPoint); 
        }

        printf("Closing Device.\n");
        usb_release_interface(udev,0);
        usb_close(udev);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In this code are using API from libusb-0.1 - but i don't know excact version of it. Probably - it is libusb-0.1.12 (it have both headers "usb.h" and "usbpp.h", which are using in this code). I have download this version on ubuntu, install it, using

```
./configure && make && make install && sudo ldconfig
```

And after that I tried to do

```
gcc -c mouse.c -w
```

to compile this code. Bit it doesnt compile. It has different errors in "usbpp.h" (in standart includes like "string" or "list") or smth else.. 
Can anyone tell me, what i'n doing fundamentally wrong? And how can i try this code?
PS - i try do test this code on ubuntu 9.04 and ubuntu 12>, both as virtual machines. It's my task in university.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usbpp.h is a c++ header file but you run gcc which is a c compiler. Run g++ instead.

Comment: it's a good idea! but now i can't take output file because of libusb library.. i try to "g++ -c mouse.cpp" and after that - "g++ -o mouse mouse.o" - there are errors only from libusb API functions. For example - "mouse.cpp:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `usb_init'". How should I compile code?

Comment: When linking you have to tell it to also link libusb. Adding -lusb to the command should take care of that.

Comment: thanks a lot! it was very stupid mistake) i use: "cc -o mouse mouse.cpp -lusb" - and my file was compile! and even work..)

Answer (score 0):

I found one another way to solve this problem:

```
gcc -o mouse ./mouse.cpp -lstdc++ -lusb
```